# How to handle currency format of decmal from sql inside of GridView Eval?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, aspxgridview, currentculture

My local machine is Turkish, if i run my asp.net aplication , i can see easly my decimal value from mysql database like below.it is my desire and everything is right what i want. i used "Text='<%#Eval("Veri","{0:N}")%>'". it is working great in my local but if i publish it result below. i want to see ny decimal like :

DB             My LOCAL GridVIEW  My Remote GridView
234567     234.567,00                  234,567.00
1234567      1.234.567,00              1,234,567.00

My GridView Code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Veri">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVeri" runat="server" MaxLength="16" Enabled="false" Text='<%#Eval("Veri","{0:N}")%>' CssClass="form-control input-sm" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my db decimal:
[image]
And my awesome result: ( I WANT THIS)
[image]

ON THE OTHER HAND : if i publish my asp.net application to Customer : ( I DONT WANT THIS)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the snippet below you can set the specific number format settings for the page with the GridView on `Page_PreInit` without changing the whole UI language. This will of course affect all number formats on the page, not just the GridView.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCultureInfo = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)newCultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();
        numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
        numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
        newCultureInfo.NumberFormat = numberFormatInfo;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCultureInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off by setting the culture.

This can be done site-wide in the web.config, using the `<globalization uiCulture="tr" culture="tr-TR" />` element, or at the page level in the page directive `<%@ Page UICulture="tr" Culture="tr-TR" %>`

Comment: This also works, but this overrides all the culture settings, not just the number formats. If that is no problem then this is indeed easier to implement.